# Properties set in Logger.BeginScope are not appearing in AWS Cloudwatch logs

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Lambda developed in C# and .Net Core 3.1. I want logs printed in Cloudwatch to include a few Properties. I have used Logger.BeginScope for the same. However the properties are not being printed with the logs.

For example, Please refer the following code:

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["AwsRequestId"] = context.AwsRequestId }))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Entered lambda {LambdaName}", context.FunctionName);
}
```

I expect the log printed in CloudWatch to have a Property named "AwsRequestId". However, as you can see in the below screenshot of the log, there is no Property. Please advise if I am missing something.

[image: Screenshot of the log from CloudWatch]

Comment: **I am not familiar with AWS** _but_ may it be neccessary to configure including scope info?

Comment: ^^ See https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#aspnet-core-logging - there is an entry in the config `IncludeScopes`. Do you have such an entry and if so, what is it set to?

Comment: Are you happy to use Serilog, If yes, then I can share a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses **Serilog** to achieve what you want.

Install following NuGet packages in your .NET Lambda function. Here, I am using .NET 6 lambda function.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Make the changes in your **Function.cs** file as shown below.

```cs
public class Function
{

    IServiceProvider provider;

    public Function()
    {
        var serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .Enrich.FromLogContext()
               .WriteTo.Console(new Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter())
               .CreateLogger();

        provider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging(item => item.AddSerilog(serilogLogger))
                .BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var _logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Function>>();

        // Logging example 1
        using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["AwsRequestId"] = context.AwsRequestId }))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Entered lambda {LambdaName}", context.FunctionName);
        }

        // Logging example 2
        _logger.LogInformation("Lambda function is invoked by {user}", "ankush jain");


        return input.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

This results logs into AWS CloudWatch like below.

[image]